# Gerrit NACR enforcement only on master - how?

Tags: prolog, gerrit

First post...

I would like to implement a NACR thats enforced only on master branch by Gerrit.

I've implemented the NACR rules.pl thats enforced on my project for all branches. But my Prolog is .. well .. non existent! So while I'm trying to get my head around it...

I'm thinking the simplest way is to combine the NACR with a predicate to remove this if the branch is not master or a release branch? Might not be so efficient, but may be simple?

[Aplogies - was only thinking in Prolog Gerrit context - there are far more Prolog folk outside this limited domain!!]

NACR - Non Author code review from https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#NonAuthorCodeReview

Here's the prolog that works and adds this NACR label to the gerrit change

```
submit_rule(S) :-
    gerrit:default_submit(X),
    X =.. [submit | Ls],
    add_non_author_approval(Ls, R),
    S =.. [submit | R].

add_non_author_approval(S1, S2) :-
    gerrit:commit_author(A),
    gerrit:commit_label(label('Code-Review', 2), R),
    R \= A, !,
    S2 = [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', ok(R)) | S1].
add_non_author_approval(S1, [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', need(_)) | S1]).
```

What I was thinking is to add something like nacr_on_master() in order to now remove the NACR label if the branch B is not the master git branch, e.g.

```
submit_rule(S) :-
    gerrit:default_submit(X),
    X =.. [submit | Ls],
    add_non_author_approval(Ls, Ri),
    nacr_on_master(Ri, R)
    S =.. [submit | R].

nacr_on_master(S1, S2) :-
  %need NACR on master
  gerrit:change_branch(B),
  B \= 'refs/heads/master',
  removehead(S1, S2). %remove last item added, which is the NACR label on head

removehead([_|Tail], Tail).

add_non_author_approval(S1, S2) :-
    gerrit:commit_author(A),
    gerrit:commit_label(label('Code-Review', 2), R),
    R \= A, !,
    S2 = [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', ok(R)) | S1].

add_non_author_approval(S1, [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', need(_)) | S1]).
```

This works where the branch B is refs/heads/master, but if its not i get an error from the Prolog engine in Gerrit

```
[
  {
    "status": "RULE_ERROR",
    "error_message": "Submit rule \u0027:(user,submit_rule)\u0027 for change 1 of proj-1-1 has no solution.",
    "prolog_reduction_count": 2766
  }
]
```

I understand what the problem might be, but I dont know how to deal with the case where a different branch to ensure there is a solution. I expect the case where there is no NACR label added there will be additional issue with my logic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please first specify what you mean with NACR? Next provide some information about what you aim to do, etc.

Comment: See the online help regarding [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: updated with details and reference. hope its not too long now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about Gerrit, but I think I understand the Prolog part of what you want to do.

I will use the following module to simulate Gerrit:

```
:- module(gerrit, [
        default_submit/1,
        commit_author/1,
        commit_label/2,
        change_branch/1
    ]).

default_submit(submit([])).

commit_author(banman).

commit_label(label('Code-Review', 2), banman).

change_branch('refs/heads/master').
%change_branch('refs/heads/changes').
```

In SWI-Prolog, this can be used from another module containing your code by adding `:- use_module(gerrit).` at the top of the file.

Then your problem boils down to the following: A call `submit_rule(S)` should always succeed. However, with your code, it only succeeds with the fact `change_branch('refs/heads/changes')`, but it fails with `change_branch('refs/heads/master')`.

I think the easiest solution is to use the original `submit_rule/1` and add an extra clause to `add_non_author_approval/2` to express your additional policy:

```
% No change to label list if we are not on master.
add_non_author_approval(S, S) :-
    gerrit:change_branch(B),
    B \= 'refs/heads/master',
    !.
```

Due to the impure control flow of the whole thing, this must be added before the other two clauses. With this you don't need your `nacr_on_master/2` predicate.

Let's test it:

```
% on master
?- submit_rule(S).
S = submit(label('Non-Author-Code-Review', need(_G2531)), []).

% on another branch
?- submit_rule(S).
S = submit([]).
```

I think this does what you want.

**Edit:** The whole code becomes much cleaner by avoiding negations and by using if-then-else instead of the cut:

```
add_non_author_approval(S1, S2) :-
    gerrit:commit_author(A),
    gerrit:commit_label(label('Code-Review', 2), R),
    (   A = R
    ->  % Author and reviewer are the same person. If we are on master,
        % require another non-author code review.
        (   gerrit:change_branch('refs/heads/master')
        ->  S2 = [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', need(_)) | S1]
        ;   % On branches other than master, nothing is needed.
            S2 = S1 )
    ;   % Author and reviewer are different persons, all is well.
        S2 = [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', ok(R)) | S1] ).
```

(Not tested.)

Comment: Many thanks. I've not tested the second cleaner option yet. But the first way not only works cleanly. But was also a little moment of enlightenment for me :)